# Best practice for encrypting user password (with RSA?) in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5, cryptography

I want to encrypt the user password before I submit it to the server in MVC 5.
I was thinking if I should use RSA to encrypt/decrypt it or their is a better way prehaps a html helper in MVC 5 for that?

I have this login form:

```
@model LoginViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Email", Value = "foo@bar.com" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Password", Value = "baz" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Best practice would be to submit the form over HTTPS. Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Interesting you mention HTTPS. That's my next task on my todo list. So if I understand you right, you "switch" to HTTPS, just _before_ you log in? I thought it was just after, when you have been authenticated. If that's the case, it's maybe better for me to jump to the HTTPS tasks and take it from their?

Comment: Oh you can submit the form over HTTPS. Can you send me a link or something I can read up on, working with MVC 5? I think it should look deeper into my theori of "switching" from HTTP to HTTPS then or what do you think?

Comment: @LukeH I don't need the site to run in HTTPS. I only need to secure the password when loging in.

Comment: @radbyx that is a common bad practice.  So once the user logs in how will you keep track that he is logged in?  I assume with a cookie right otherwise he will be prompted to login on every single action.  So you encrypt the password but transmit the authentication token in the clear.  Then the attacker will ignore the password and just steal the token/cookie to impersonate the user.  Also the only way you are going to encrypt the password is clientside, which means in javascript so how are you going to prevent the attacker from just spoofing the javascript?

Comment: @GeraldDavis Davis Okay i hear you, it make sense. I was planning making and OWIN User Cookie with Claims in MVC 5. But yeah if the cookie is so free and clear as you say(and i believe you), then I see you're point on making the site HTTPS all the way after the log in. The only issue I have, is that in my compagny we talked a little about our customer don't want the "trouble" with an SSL certificate. (I assume it's 100% nesessary to have on if you're going the HTTPS way). Thanks for input alot!

Comment: @radbyx.  One final change is to make the entire site (even the public part) https as well.  ssl/tls is "cheap" compared to modern CPUs and the most expensive part is the key exchange.  While you are at it consider https ONLY and then force it using HSTS.

Comment: We ships a MSI to our customers with the website, for them to install on their own IIS. Hence it would be easier if their wasn't any need for a Certificate, because then all the Customers have to have one on their IIS, if I understand it correct. It's all somewhat new to me.